# hibernate criteria with count and groupby query

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to convert following query to hibernate criteria query. Please help

somehow following createQuery is not working due to composite primary key on Votes table where i have separated primary key with @Embeddable

```
session.createQuery("select V.Vote_Option, count(V.Vote_Option) from Votes  V where V.Event_ID ="+eventId+" group by V.Vote_Option").list()
```

I tried with the following criteria. need help to correct it.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Votes.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Event_ID", eventId));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("Vote_Option"))
            .add(Projections.property("count(Vote_Option)"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("Vote_Option")));

    List<String> showVotes= criteria.list();
```

following is the structure of my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Votes")

public class Votes {

public Votes(){}

@EmbeddedId
private Vote vote;

@Column(name = "Vote_Option")
private int Vote_Option;
//setter getters...
```

and Embeddable object for composite primary key

```
  @Embeddable
  public class Vote implements Serializable{

    public Vote(){}

    @Column(name="Event_ID")
    private int Event_ID;

    @Column(name="Voter_MSISDN")
    private long Voter_MSISDN;

     //setter getters...
```

Please suggest a better way here..

Answer (score 0):

The `add(Projections.property("count(Vote_Option)"))` wont work.
You need to use `criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())` in order to support the count.

Comment: I did not get how "Long resultCount" uniqueResult will give the desired result.. In original query I want the count with groupby Vote_option... so i am expecting a result in multiple rows..

Comment: When used modified criteria as follow  add(Projections.count("Vote_Option")) ... for this i am receiving the  error as "could not resolve property: Event_ID of: com.sms.smsapp.Votes".... apperantly I am not able to map the criteria to the Embeddable entitiy Vote.Event_ID

Comment: You should use `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("vote.Event_ID", eventId));`

Answer (score 0):

By the way i achieved the list using createQury as follows
Used embeddable entity to map
change from V.Event_ID to V.vote.Event_ID ... vote being @Embeddable

```
 session.createQuery("select V.Vote_Option, count(V.Vote_Option) from Votes  V where V.vote.Event_ID ="+eventId+" group by V.Vote_Option").list();
```